# How can I find the LinkedIn profile of any given Facebook user?

Tags: javascript, ruby, facebook, pattern-matching, linkedin-api

So assume I have a list of Facebook members without having their actual email. What is the best way to find the LinkedIn profile of every Facebook user on my list? What clues can I use to do the matching?

I'd appreciate your input. Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I think the downvotes, rude comment, and close votes on this question are completely unnecessary. What the OP is asking is clear. If what he wants to do is impossible, just answer the question and say that it's impossible. I vote to reopen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a company called PIPL which has an API which might be helpful... I haven't looked at it for a while so I'm not sure if they have data on LinkedIn handles.

Basically, they compile lots of data about people from different sources, and allow you to search their DB using things like Facebook handles, e-mail addresses, etc. So for example, you can search for a list of e-mail addresses, and retrieve Facebook names for at least some of those people.

It's not 100% accurate but their data is fairly good.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. I don't know why the question was voted down (it was definitely not appreciated). I think we're going to try out PIPL's API.

Comment: Have a look at their docs, and maybe even send them an e-mail to see if they actually have data on LinkedIn account names. If they don't, then you are back to square 1. If they do, you can use the API for free if your daily usage is not too much (at least last time I checked).